# How to make my discord bot only reply question in specific channel?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to make my discord bot only reply to question on a specific channel. Here is the example:

Channel A:

User A: Dream!

Discord Bot: You are Dream's big fans? Oh me too!

Channel B:

User A: Dream!

Discord Bot: "No Respond"

I want to make something like this. If it is possible, please help me! This is part of my code:

```
import discord
import time
import random

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('{0.user} has already login!'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    name = message.author.display_name
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith("Hey Rikky!"):
        await message.channel.send('Always Here!')

    if "Rikky, tell me a joke" in message.content:
        await message.channel.send("I'm sorry, I'm not good at telling someone jokes")

client.run('My token')
```

Thanks for spending so much time reading this question! Thank you! (I'm using discord.py)

Comment: You could either only allow the bot in the relevant channel, or alternatively just check to see if the correct channel is on the `message` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the message's channel id with message.channel.id before replying:

```
if message.content.startswith("Hey Rikky!") and message.channel.id == "YourChannelId":
    await message.channel.send('Always Here!')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have it say the following

```
if message.channel.name == 'Your channel name here':
```

You can also use the channel id

```
if message.channel.id == 'Channel ID here':
```

So the final structure would be

```
if message.channel.name == 'channel name here':
    if message.content.startswith...
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I believe this could be solved by simple additional if statement. Message form discord API has attribute channel (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message#message)
So if message.channel == "whatever channel You have in mind" should solve your problem.
Alternatively you can set bot permissions from server side directly from discord. You can add him only to one specific channel and don't bother with additional coding.

Comment: This is a good idea, but what I want to do is not just let it know are they talking to it. I hope I can use this method to make it understand other messages more clearly. Anyway, thanks for your idea.